# Flaw in finding $f(x)$ when $f(0)=1$ and $f(10-x)=f(x), f(2-x)=f(2+x), \forall x \in R$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Finding, the function $f(x)$ when $$f(0)=1 ~\text{and}~ f(10-x)=f(x), f(2-x)=f(2+x), \forall x \in R.......(1)$$

Let $x \to 2-x$ in $f(10-x)=f(x) \implies f(8+x)=f(2-x)=f(2+x)$

Next, we take $x\to x-2$ in above to get $f(6+x)=f(x), \forall x \in R$, implying that $f(x)$ is periodic with period $6$.

However, $f(x)=\cos(\pi x)$ does satisfy all of $(1)$ but $f(x)=\cos(\pi x/3)$ fails to do so. Where/What is the discrepancy?

Comment: Is having a period of 6 a necessary AND sufficient condition?

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ is a solution.

Comment: Such an $f$ is determined by its restriction to the half period $[-1,2]$

Comment: You derived the implication "If $f$ satisfies this, then $f$ has period $6$. The other implication is not necessarily true. So you could find a function like $\cos(\pi x/3)$ that has period $6$ but does not satisfy your equation.